# uberSVN doesn't show up at server IP

Tags: apache, svn, windows-server-2008-x64, ubersvn

I am investigating different versioning systems for my company and am currently looking in to using uberSVN, but I'm running in to a problem. I've gone through the installation, apparently successfully, but I can't access the server anywhere except the loopback IP (127.0.0.1). When I run it from the loopback it runs perfectly well, but I can't call it from the server name at the domain or from it's regular IP address. It seems it should be easy enough to configure this, but I'm finding precious little in my searches. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The installation is the latest version of uberSVN, downloaded from their site today. I'm installing it on Windows Server 2008 64 bit.

UPDATE: This may be due to our firewall blocking the necessary ports. I will update with the answer if that is it. Otherwise I will update if it did not solve the problem.

UPDATE: We did have a problem with our firewall blocking port 9890 as well as Windows Firewall blocking port 9890. This problem is now solved. I will answer and mark answered once the requisite amount of time has passed for me to do so, unless someone else puts it in an answer first. In which case, I'll be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the firewall allows traffic to the port you have assigned to uberSVN and that that Windows Firewall is either off, or allows traffic to that port as well.

Answer (score 0):

UberSVN isn't pure VCS per se, it's Subversion plus Frontend + Administration + ... Full ALM tool as result (big and complex). It was **bad idea** to start with UberSVN without SVN and|or SVN+Apache background

You was too fast and inattentive at install stage and on step 10 (See it in [UberSVN Doc](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/#I13)) didn't redefine Base URL

> This the IP address of the computer on which you are installing
>   uberSVN. You should ensure that this is a proper IP address, no
>   'localhost' or the 127. loopback address (see the box, below) as these
>   will not work for users connecting accross a network. The IP address
>   will for the basis for the address used for accessing uberSVN and
>   Subversion

Now you have to fix your settings in [UberSVN administration](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/#R73)

Comment: No, actually I wasn't. I paid perfectly close attention and edited those properly. As it turns out, the Windows Firewall was blocking the connection.